# QR scanner returns a value different from the one I pass to it

Tags: java, encryption, base64, qr-code

Please, do not pay attention to algorithm for encoding/ image size/ password etc. It is a demo. 
I generate qr code this way :

```
private final byte[] keyValue =
        new byte[]{'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'};


public String generateQR(ConsumerDto consumerDto) {
    CryptoUtil cryptoUtil = new CryptoUtil(keyValue);
    String encryptedConsumerDto = cryptoUtil.encrypt(String.valueOf(consumerDto));

    String resultImage = "";
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(consumerDto)) {
        QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(encryptedConsumerDto,
                    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 500, 500, getHintsForEncoding());
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", outputStream);
            resultImage = "data:image/png;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray());
            return resultImage;
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return resultImage;
}
```

After the generation when I return back the value to front end, it is in base64:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

But when front end tries to scan the code (by any qr-scanner), he gets this value :

```
zrzVfLTvdptoDEM0mDM795LN7xsiK8OND74EPuDfcc+pxniItkpDACO0yssEHNNrX6IdccyeyTlrDBmIsaETv5xsOMjOpLY0ZelX/kkyjwr7UQR59VmKLf4a7EwBlMGZsKFIpQoqXVptAEBDthL78QsJahLpCCtq7bcsOv9DUhjCz5P1j3Ai5GZ1xGobuVXRkLn0SYJInjPeSHihjcx47Q==
```

I need to get from front end same base64 string as I gave him encoded to be able to decode it later.
Here is a cryptoutil I use to encode/decode objects:

```
public class CryptoUtil {

private static final String CRYPTO_ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CryptoUtil.class);
private static final byte[] keyValue =
        new byte[]{'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y'};


private final Key key;
private final Cipher cipher = getCipherInstance();

public CryptoUtil(byte[] key) {
    this.key = new SecretKeySpec(key, CRYPTO_ALGORITHM);
}

private Cipher getCipherInstance() {
    try {
        return Cipher.getInstance(CRYPTO_ALGORITHM);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Crypto error: Unable to get cipher instance");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public String encrypt(String password) {
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes());
        return new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Crypto error: Unable to encrypt password");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public String decrypt(String encryptedPassword) {
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decodedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedPassword);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(decodedValue), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Crypto error: Unable to encrypt password");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: When I do not encode it in any way, it returns a string value of consumerDto object. Without this confusement.

Comment: Your encryption and decryption algorithms appear to work just fine therefore it must be where it is converted to QR Code OR the QR Scanner is obviously not providing the QR code expected. What is the **getHintsForEncoding()** method? Where in the world does that come from? Maybe, just maybe, that method is screwing things up a little bit like changing the Character set.